# how does the expression b=${b:-"/data"} work

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I've run a cross a shell script with `BUILDDIR=${BUILDDIR:-"/data"}` which , upon experimentation, takes the original BUILDDIR if it exists and isnt an empty string, and otherwise sets it to /data.
What I don't understand is how the expression works - why the `:` and `-` operators and how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of (fortunately only) a handful of shortcuts done as part of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). In short, there's the following, loosely defined:

- `${VAR:-value}` Use `$VAR` if possible, else `value`
- `${VAR:=value}` Use `$VAR` if possible, else set `$VAR` to `value` and use `value`
- `${VAR:?value}` (exit if `$VAR` is undefined) and `${VAR:+value}` (opposite of `:-` ) exist, but I've never seen them in the wild.
- `${VAR:offset}` and `${VAR:offset:length}` take substrings of `$VAR`.

(There's also a bunch of others that remove prefixes or suffixes or do general substitution; please see the bash info page linked above for those.)